# Get different strings from a file and write a .txt

Tags: python, string, file, parsing, logging

I'am trying to get lines from a text file (.log) into a .txt document.

I need get into my .txt file the same data. But the line itself is sometimes different. From what I have seen on internet, it's usualy done with a pattern that will anticipate how the line is made.

```
1525:22Player 11 spawned with userinfo: \team\b\forcepowers\0-5-030310001013001131\ip\46.98.134.211:24806\rate\25000\snaps\40\cg_predictItems\1\char_color_blue\34\char_color_green\34\char_color_red\34\color1\65507\color2\14942463\color3\2949375\color4\2949375\handicap\100\jp\0\model\desann/default\name\Faybell\pbindicator\1\saber1\saber_malgus_broken\saber2\none\sex\male\ja_guid\420D990471FC7EB6B3EEA94045F739B7\teamoverlay\1
```

The line i'm working with usualy looks like this. The data i'am trying to collect are :

```
\ip\0.0.0.0
\name\NickName_of_the_player
\ja_guid\420D990471FC7EB6B3EEA94045F739B7
```

And print these data, inside a .txt file. Here is my current code.
As explained above, i'am unsure about what keyword to use for my research on google. And how this could be called (Because the string isn't the same?)

I have been looking around alot, and most of the test I have done, have allowed me to do some things, but i'am not yet able to do as explained above. So i'am in hope for guidance here :) (Sorry if i'am noobish, I understand alot how it works, I just didn't learned language in school, I mostly do small scripts, and usualy they work fine, this time it's way harder)

```
def readLog(filename):

  with open(filename,'r') as eventLog:
    data = eventLog.read()
    dataList = data.splitlines()
  
    return dataList


    eventLog = readLog('games.log')
```

Comment: You want to split on a delimiter. Using a backslash as the delimiter is fairly horrible, but I guess you can't change that. In Python, you need to double the backslash to escape it; `line.split('\\')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read the files in "raw" mode rather than as strings. When reading the file from disk, use `open(filename,'rb')`. To use your example, I ran

```
text_input = r"1525:22Player 11 spawned with userinfo: \team\b\forcepowers\0-5-030310001013001131\ip\46.98.134.211:24806\rate\25000\snaps\40\cg_predictItems\1\char_color_blue\34\char_color_green\34\char_color_red\34\color1\65507\color2\14942463\color3\2949375\color4\2949375\handicap\100\jp\0\model\desann/default\name\Faybell\pbindicator\1\saber1\saber_malgus_broken\saber2\none\sex\male\ja_guid\420D990471FC7EB6B3EEA94045F739B7\teamoverlay\1"
text_as_array = text_input.split('\\')
```

You'll need to know which columns contain the strings you care about. For example,

```
with open('output.dat','w') as fil:
    fil.write(text_as_array[6])
```

You can figure these array positions from the sample string

```
>>> text_as_array[6]
'46.98.134.211:24806'
>>> text_as_array[34]
'Faybell'
>>> text_as_array[44]
'420D990471FC7EB6B3EEA94045F739B7'
```

If the column positions are not consistent but the key-value pairs are always adjacent, we can leverage that

```
>>> text_as_array.index("ip")
5
>>> text_as_array[text_as_array.index("ip")+1]
'46.98.134.211:24806'
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Yet the columns in this strings are not always at the same position. It is why i'am concerned on how to do so.

Thanks alot for your answer, you managed to give me more knowledge around this already. :)

Comment: If the positions are not consistent, are the key-value pairs always adjacent? I've added a snippet to the end of my post about accessing data by key name.